# How to write API for updation of json data in node js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have json object in front end while changing any object value ,that should be changed in Backend.we are using Node.js in Backend .For that I have to write API.How do I write .I am new to node js.

updateCountryConfig(config:any): Observable {
const url = `${AppConst.API_BASE_URL}/settings/update-config`;
return this.http.post(url,config)
}

I have written like this in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic question, but you can create your API using Node JS and Express JS. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8bbbcskNkM&t=1s) and it will show you some basics.

Here is the code for a simple REST API,

Initialize your Node JS project with,

```sh
npm init
```

You will be asked to fill all of the below information for your project.

Once this command is run, you will have a [**package.json**](/package.json) created.

Create your /src folder and app.js file.

```sh
mkdir src 

cd src 

touch app.js
```

Add the following code in your /src/app.js file.

```js
console.log("I love tutorials from With Chanakya!");
```

Install express using npm as a dependency and nodemon as a dev-dependency.

```sh
npm install --save express

npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Run the code with,

```sh
nodemon app.js
```

You can always use ctrl+c to come out of nodemon.

Update your [**package.json**](/package.json) to have a start script.

```js
{
  "name": "dog-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "REST API that retrieves dog breeds ",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js"
  },
  "author": "Chanakya Lokam",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Create basic REST API - refer to /src folder for soure code. We will create the following files,

**app.js**

```js
// console.log("Subscribe to my channel - With Chanakya!");

//Import modules
const express = require("express");
const dogRoutes = require("./routes/dog.routes");

// Define PORT for HTTP Server
const PORT = 9900;

// Initialize Express
const app = express();

app.use(dogRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  console.log(`Server is up at localhost ${PORT}`);
});
```

**/routes/dog.routes.js**

```js
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

// Define Dog Breeds array
const dogs = [
  { id: "1", name: "Happy", breed: "Golden Retriever" },
  { id: "2", name: "Silky", breed: "Labrador" },
  { id: "3", name: "Mika", breed: "Husky" },
];

// GET route for Dogs
router.get("/dogs", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send(dogs);
});

// GET route for Dog Breed Search
router.get("/dog/:name", (req, res) => {
  var notFound = true;
  // Find dog breed based on name
  dogs.forEach((dog) => {
    if (dog.name == req.params.name) {
      //res.status(200).send(`${req.params.name} is a ${dog.breed}`);
      notFound = false;
      res.status(200).send(dog);
    }
  });

  if (notFound) res.sendStatus(404);
});

module.exports = router;
```

You can now run your API using nodemon and test the routes in [**Postman**](https://www.postman.com/) (or) using [**curl**](https://curl.se/).